# Cloud HTTPS Functions: returning a Promise which is inside a Promisee

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently working on an HTTPS Cloud Function using Firebase, consisting in deleting the post my Android user requested.

## General idea

The workflow is (the whole code is available at the end of this SO Question): 1) Firebase checks the user identity (`admin.auth().verifyIdToken`) ; 2) Firestore gets data from the post that must be deleted (`deleteDbEntry.get().then()`) ; 3) Cloud Storage prepares itself to delete the file found in the gotten data (`.file(filePath).delete()`) ; 4) Firestore prepares a batch to delete the post (`batch.delete(deleteDbEntry);`) and to update the likes/unlikes using the gotten data (`batch.update(updateUserLikes,`) ; 5) executes the promise of the deletion of the file and of the batch (`return Promise.all([deleteFile, batch_commit])`).

## Expected behavior

I would want to check the user identity. If it's successful, to get the requested post to delete's data using Firebase. If it's successful, I would want to execute the Firestore batch plus the Cloud Storage file deletion in the same promise (that's why I use `Promise.all([deleteFile, batch_commit]).then()`). If the identity check fails, or if the data get fails, or if the batch fails, I would want to tell the Android app. If all successes, idem.

As all of these operations are in a Cloud HTTPS Function, I must return a promise. This promise, I think, would correspond to all that operations if they are successful, or to an error if at least one is not (?).

## Actual behavior

For the moment, I just return the promise of the Firebase user identity check.

## My problem & My question

I can't go from the actual behavior to the expected behavior because:

1. I think it's not very clear in my mind whether I should return the promise corresponding to "all these operations are successful, or at least one is not" in this Cloud HTTPS Function
2. As these operations are nested (except the Firestorage file deletion + Firestore post deletion which are present in a batch), I can't return something like `Promise.all()`.

### My question

Could you please tell me if I'm right (point 1.) and, if not: what should I do? If yes: how could I do it, because of point 2.?

## Whole Firebase Cloud HTTPS Function code

*Note: I've removed my input data controls to make my code more lisible.*

```
exports.deletePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
          .then(function(decodedToken) {
            const uid = decodedToken.uid;

            const type_of_post = data.type_of_post;
            const the_post = data.the_post;
            const deleteDbEntry = admin_firestore.collection('list_of_' + type_of_post).doc(the_post);
            const promise = deleteDbEntry.get().then(function(doc) {

                const filePath = type_of_post + '/' + uid + '/' + data.stored_image_name;
                const deleteFile = storage.bucket('android-f.appspot.com').file(filePath).delete();

                const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
                batch.delete(deleteDbEntry);
                if(doc.data().number_of_likes > 0) {
                    const updateUserLikes = admin_firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
                    batch.update(updateUserLikes, "likes", FieldValue.increment(-doc.data().number_of_likes));
                }
                const batch_commit = batch.commit();

                return Promise.all([deleteFile, batch_commit]).then(function() {
                    return 1;
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unable to delete the post. (2)');
                });

            }).catch(function(error) { 
                console.log(error);
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unable to delete the post. (1)');
            });

            return promise;


          }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An error occurred while verifying the token.');
          });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that you are actually defining a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and not an [HTTPS one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), since you do:

```
exports.deletePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {..});
```

One of the advantages of a Callable Cloud Function over an HTTPS one is that it "automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens".

So you can simply get the user `uid` with `context.auth.uid;`.

---

Now, regarding the way of "orchestrating" the different calls, IMHO you should just chain the different Promises returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods (the ones of Firestore and the one of Cloud Storage), as follows:

```
exports.deletePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    //....
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    let number_of_likes;

    const type_of_post = data.type_of_post;
    const the_post = data.the_post;
    const deleteDbEntry = admin_firestore.collection('list_of_' + type_of_post).doc(the_post);

    return deleteDbEntry.get()
        .then(doc => {
            number_of_likes = doc.data().number_of_likes;
            const filePath = type_of_post + '/' + uid + '/' + data.stored_image_name;
            return storage.bucket('android-f.appspot.com').file(filePath).delete();

        })
        .then(() => {

            const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
            batch.delete(deleteDbEntry);

            if (number_of_likes > 0) {
                const updateUserLikes = admin_firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
                batch.update(updateUserLikes, "likes", FieldValue.increment(-doc.data().number_of_likes));
            }

            return batch.commit();

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('....', '.....');
        });

});
```

I don't think using `Promise.all()` will bring any interest, in your case, because, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), "if any of the passed-in promises reject, `Promise.all` asynchronously rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, **whether or not the other promises have resolved**".

At the time of writing, there is no way to group all of these asynchronous calls to different Firebase services  into one atomic operation.

Even if the batched write at the end is atomic, it could happen that the file in Cloud Storage is correctly deleted but that the batched write to Firestore is not executed, for example because there is a problem with the Firestore service.

---

Also, note that you only need one exception handler at the end of the Promise chain. If you want to differentiate the cause of the exception, in such a way that you send a different error message to the front-end you could use the approach presented in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e).

The article shows how to define different custom Error classes (derived from the standard built-in Error object) which are used to check the kind of error in the exception handler.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Have a look at the update. I've just realized that you need to pass a value coming from the `deleteDbEntry` doc to the second `then()`. You could also execute the batched write before deleting the Cloud Storage file: like this no need to have a "global" `number_of_likes`variable.